# Does a Thor take 3 or 4 volleys to kill two (2) hydras?

Tags: starcraft-2

VS. ground Thors do 30 Damage per attack with 2 attacks.
Hydras have 80 health.
The Thor's attacks are staggered (not like the phoenix that makes both laser attacks at the same time).

Back to the question at hand: When a Thor is fighting 2 hydras (no upgrades on anything) will the Thor make a total of 3 or 4 full volleys? (1 volley being both attacks)
After the first volley the target hydra has 20 health. So, does the next volley finish off the target hydra and hit the second hydra once or does the attacking delay trigger on switching targets ultimately requiring the Thor to make a fourth attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four

The way multiple attack work is:

2. the weapon acquires a target
3. the weapon fires its attacks (all of them)
4. the animation for the attacks is displayed (usually a projectile, but not in the case of a Thor)
5. the projectile collides
6. the damage is applied on a per projectile basis
7. the unit take decides if it is dead

Comment: @tzenesSo you should see the second attack animation from the Thor but essentially on the corpse of the hydra and the damage applied to nothing or the second attack just doesn't go off but either way it takes 4 to kill both.